iptables rule list Warning: Extension CONNMARK is not supported, missing kernel module?
I am using ubuntu image to run pod container. And wish to using iptables to do sidecar inbound traffic hijack .
now we use apt-get install iptables only get iptables V1.8
However, we have both kernel 3.10.x and 5.10.x machines on production. so we have to use iptables legacy .
here is the probelem, when list rules, we got
Warning: Extension CONNMARK is not supported, missing kernel module?
CONNMARK   all  --  anywhere             anywhere             CONNMARK save

on node :
uname -r
3.10.0-957.12.1.el7.x86_64

cat /boot/config-3.10.0-957.12.1.el7.x86_64 |grep CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_CONNMARK
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_CONNMARK=m

iptables -V
iptables v1.4.21

And the Warning is not exists on node, when exec command: iptables -t mangle -L
inside container:
$ iptables -V
iptables v1.8.10 (legacy)
$ which iptables
/usr/sbin/iptables
$ ls -alh /usr/sbin/iptables
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 Apr  8  2024 /usr/sbin/iptables -> /etc/alternatives/iptables
$ ls -alh /etc/alternatives/iptables
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 Oct 23 17:55 /etc/alternatives/iptables -> /usr/sbin/iptables-legacy

Dockerfile

FROM --platform=amd64 ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get isntall -y iptables
RUN update-alternatives --set iptables /usr/sbin/iptables-legacy 

One more thing: function works well, except for this warning.
and when using centos7 image to do the same work, not see warning too , and iptables version v1.4.21
So, my question is , where is this warning come from? what does the effect?
PS: why using connmark is another story, not discuss here.

You need to load the necessary modules on the host. Containers share the kernel, and only privileged ones can ever load modules.

thanks for the reply. but the modules is loaded on the host already i think. since function works well, i mean the tproxy redirect. when change to centos image,no warning. so the host kernel load should not be the problem.  i really think it might some config in ubuntu image or kenerl related whatever.
